# Parse an array from ASP to Javascript and have an output in a div tag

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp-classic

In the following code I want to parse an array from ASP to a Javascript array, choose an array index in Javascript and output the value of the index in a div tag on a press of a button. This piece of coding is only one part of a larger code and i need to figure out this part to move on to the other that will also be in Javascript.

Here is the code in a .asp file:

```
    <%

    Dim va(3)
    va(0) = 2
    va(1) = 3
    va(2) = 4

    %>

    <html>

    <button onclick="func()">Press</button>
    <div id="mydiv"></div>

<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>


    function func(){
    ba = new Array();

    i = 0;
    while(i < 3){
    ba[i]=<%=va(i)%>;
    i++;
    }


    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML=ba[2];
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Currently the code keeps on returning the value of the first index in the array, regardless of what index i choose in this line -  `document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML=ba[2];`.
For instance the result should show 4, but it keeps giving me 2 in my div tag. If i replace the `while` loop with:

```
ba[0]=<%=va(0)%>;
ba[1]=<%=va(1)%>;
ba[2]=<%=va(2)%>;
```

it works, but i will be having much bigger arrays in the future to deal with. I also tried a `for` loop,  `ba = new Array(<%=va%>);`, but no luck. How can i use a loop to do this. It seem very simple but i can't seem to get it to work, any advice is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have such code instead:

```
function func(){
    ba = [<%=Join(va, ", ")%>];
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML=ba[2];
}
```

The output will be something like:

```
ba = [2, 3, 4];
```

Which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have written your loop in JavaScript (client side code). You need to loop through your server side array with server side code and output client side code and data. Try something like:

```
For i = LBound(va) To UBound(va)
    Response.Write "ba[" & i & "] = " & va(i) & ";" & vbcrlf
Next
```

I would question this method of transferring data between the server and client side though, perhaps look into some ASP classic JSON libraries, for example.